# How to know which activity clicked the button?

Tags: android

I have 10 activites that extends baseActivity. My BaseActivity basically has a help menu icon. When the user press the help menu Icon, I should display the help menu for that activity. How can I know which activity called the help menu so I know which xml resource to display

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.help_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.help_menu_item:
                    displayHelpMenu();          
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    protected void displayHelpMenu(){

             // I will load the xml to the textview and display it in dialog. How can I know which xml resource to load

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to find out the `Activity` is to use `instanceOf`. Something like this:

```
protected void displayHelpMenu() {
    // I will load the xml to the textview and display it in dialog.
    // How can I know which xml resource to load

    if(this instanceOf DerivedActivity.class) {
        // load XML file
    }
    else if(...) {
    ...
    }
}
```

However, in my opinion, while this solves your problem, this is not the correct way of doing things. In OOP when you end up with a situation like this, you should make use of *method overriding*.

The `base class` defines general functionality of loading the resource, while the derived class should provide the name of the file to load. In other words, the `base class` should not know about the `derived class`. A better solution would be:

```
protected void displayHelpMenu() {

    // ask each child class for the help menu resource file
    int resId = getHelpMenuResource();

    // write code to load XML file with resId
    ...
    ...
}

protected int getHelpMenuResource() {
    return defaultMenuId;
}
```

Now in your derived class, `@Override` the `getHelpMenuResource()` method and return resource id specific to that activity.

Comment: Great solutions. I like the alternatives .. Accepted:)

Answer (score 1):

how about make your BaseActivity abstract and add a getMenuResource method?

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.help_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.help_menu_item:
                    displayHelpMenu();          
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } 
    }

    protected void displayHelpMenu(){

             // I will load the xml to the textview and display it in dialog. How can I know which xml resource to load
        int menuResourceId = getMenuResourceId();
        // do the rest
    }

    public abstract int getMenuResourceId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. good solution but the other person beats you to it :)